# Custom table name for a model in laminas

Tags: laminas

I've started learning laminas by reading it's documentation (`Album` model and table).  I have a `product` model and I want to fetch the records but the problem is that the name of my table is `tbl_product` and I get this error:

> Statement could not be executed (42S02 - 1146 - Table
> 'project.product' doesn't exist)

Where can I define the table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that by "reading it's documentation" you are talking about [Laminas' tutorial](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/), then the answer can be found under the the [Database and Models section](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/)

When you define a new model, you must update the module's configuration, specifying where the application will find the [model's factory and gateway](https://docs.laminas.dev/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable):

```php
// Add this method:
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => [
            Model\AlbumTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\AlbumTableGateway::class);
                return new Model\AlbumTable($tableGateway);
            },
            Model\AlbumTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Album());
                return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ],
    ];
}
```

The class that contains the db table information is `TableGateway`, which constructor is:

```php
public function __construct(
    $table,
    AdapterInterface $adapter,
    $features = null,
    ?ResultSetInterface $resultSetPrototype = null,
    ?Sql $sql = null
)
```

The first parameter is the table's name. 
Hence, in your configuration, you need something like:

```php
Model\ProductTable::class => function($container) {
    $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\ProductTableGateway::class);
    return new Model\ProductTable($tableGateway);
},
Model\ProductTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Product());
    return new TableGateway('tbl_product', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
},
```